# How to time(interval) addition in postgres functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, intervals

I have the following code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getcompletepause(VARIADIC arr text[])
RETURNS interval 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

declare

slice TEXT[]; 
blancotime interval;
returnval interval; --Buffervalue
timetime interval;


begin


blancotime = '00:00:00';

FOR i IN 1..array_length($1,1) BY 1 loop

slice := $1[i:i+1];

returnval = slice[1];

END LOOP;
timetime= returnval + returnval;
return returnval;
END;
$function$
;
```

And my input parameter is looking like this:

```
select getcompletepause('00:01:20','01:10:00',...) --variadic parameter input
```

And I want that all times that are Incoming will be additioned to one complet time like

01:11:20 ,that´s the complete time of the 2 inputs

Can you help me with this ? Thanks guys !

Comment: If you want to add intervals, you should _pass_ intervals, rather than strings that look like `time` values

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a loop or even PL/pgSQL:

Just cast the input values to `interval` and aggregate on the array elements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getcompletepause(VARIADIC arr text[])
  RETURNS interval 
  LANGUAGE sql
AS
$function$
  select sum(d::interval)
  from unnest(arr) as t(d);
$function$
;
```

---

The correct way to [iterate over the elements of the array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) is to use `foreach`. Then you can simply add the values to the return value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getcompletepause(VARIADIC arr text[])
RETURNS interval 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

declare
  returnval interval;
  slice text;
begin
  returnval := '0'::interval;
  foreach slice in array arr loop
    returnval := returnval + slice::interval;
  end loop;

  return returnval;
END;
$function$
;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=55650558fb0db263e0b2fe3a95aa345b)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your code. Your code caused for me the following error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "arr"
  Position: 303

Comment: @ChristophD: sorry, typo (but the first one is better anyway)